# Android updating Button background in separate Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a bunch of Buttons (custom, with a few extra methods to apply other backgrounds, and revert to original), which can be assigned a background. But since I don't know how large these backgrounds will or can be, I decided to set the background in a separate Thread. First, I had this code:

```
public void updateButton(final Button b, final String d, final String s) {
    b.nullify(); //Recycles previous background, else OOM error
    b.setText(s);
    if (d != null) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                b.setBackgroundFromBase64(d);
            }
        }.run();
    }
    else b.setBackgroundToDefault(); //Sets standard android background
}
```

but I soon found out that this wasn't the way to go. Slowly, the memory got flooded when I called this method a few thousand times. When I removed the `new Thread()` part, the memory wasn't flooded, so the Thread was the cause of this (Memory Analyzer Tool told me the same).

Then I tried the `AsyncTask`:

```
private class UpdateButtonTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {
    @Override 
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... objs) {
        String s = (String)objs[0];
        Button b = (Button)objs[1];
        String d = (String) objs[2];
        b.nullify(); //Recycles previous background, else OOM error
        b.setText(s);
        if (d != null) b.setBackgroundFromBase64(d);
        else b.setBackgroundToDefault();
        return null;
     }
     @Override
     protected void onProgressUpdate(Void v) {
         //As far as I know, I don't need this method
     }
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
         //Neither this one
     }
 }
```

and call

```
new UpdateButtonTask().execute("Button", myButton, base64String);
```

in the button update method. But that didn't work either (the button wasn't updated at all. No text, no custom background). I read some articles and questions about Threading ([this](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/), [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), and  [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html) amongst others), but I can't seem to get it working. For now, *no* Thread and hoping the phones are fast enough to not cause trouble on the UI thread seems to be the best option, but I'd rather have something more reliable, like a Thread.
**What am I doing wrong?** or maybe just the full question **How can I update a Button background on a background Thread** (so the UI doesn't stop working when applying larger backgrounds)**?**

Comment: First of all, your solution with `Thread` didn't produce a separate thread, you just ran the `run()` method on the same thread from an anonymous class. You should use `Thread.start()` to run it in a separate thread. But you shouldn't use `Thread` anyway, so nevermind that. Secondly, could you please elaborate on how the solution with the `AsyncTask` doesn't work? What is expected and what happens?

Comment: see addition. The button just wasn't updated at all. No custom background, no text on button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the problem is that you're trying to update the UI on a non-UI thread. This throws an exception and kills your `AsyncTask`.

You should separate the processing-intensive tasks to the `AsyncTask` and then apply UI changes on the main thread (using `runOnUiThread(Runnable)`).

Since you're using a custom button, I don't really know what you're not allowed to do on a non-UI thread. I'm guessing the `setText` function is causing problems, if you haven't overridden it.

You should start by wrapping the whole body of your `doInBackground` method in a `try/catch` block and logging the exception to isolate the problem.

Comment: You can also use onPostExecute() which is guaranteed to be on the Handler which started the AsyncTask. I assume you started the async task on the UI Thread. It's usually best to update view components on the UI thread to avoid issues such as this. Most of the time they aren't that intensive since the actual draw happens at a separate step.

Answer (score -1):

May be this code will help you

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

public void run() {

context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

public void run() {
      b.setBackgroundFromBase64(d);
}

});

}

}).start();
```

Comment: And this code doesn't interfere with the idea that I do not want the UI Thread to wait for it? Or is it still a different Thread? Sorry, kinda confused.

Comment: This code would run a separate thread from the UI thread, which would enqueue `b.setBackgroundFromBase64(d);` back onto the UI thread, effectively doing the same as just calling `b.setBackgroundFromBase64(d);` from the UI thread in the first place.

Comment: I am using same code to set image in ListView in each cell.for avoiding jerky effect in List view . And it worked for me .